# partial views or parse data mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am fairly new to MVC, and web programming in general.  I spent most of my career on Microsoft desktop applications.  I have a MVC dashboard project I am working on where we want to display chunks of data in several locations on one main page.  Right now I have this set up to use partial views in MVC, and have separate sql views for each partial view.  My question is one of performance.  Is it better to set up a view in sql for each partial view in MVC, or is it better to have one view in sql, and use linq expressions in code to parse out the needed data.  The data changes frequently, so I'm not sure which route to go.  Or maybe there is a totally different way???  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  I should clarify maybe.  I am trying to choose between several views in sql, and partial views in mvc, or one view in sql and parsing the data to one view in mvc.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: depends. or you can just write some queries to fetch the data. Sql view is like a named query anyways. it doesn't provide any performance benefit unless its a materialized view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple views might save you a tiny tiny bit of bandwidth, because you can tailor the column lists to get only what you need and no more. But if that sort of performance is important to you, it'd probably much better to get rid of the design that causes you to retrieve the same data multiple times. A couple ideas:

(1) Get rid of the partial views. Instead, retrieve the data once, as JSON; parse the response; and use client-side Javascript (or JQuery or Knockout) to get the data where it needs to go on the page.

(2) Develop some sort of caching mechanism to allow your partial views to retrieve data from the same data cache, which can be populated using the single view.